# Convergence of exponentially decaying sublinear sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, rate-of-convergence

I am looking at the following sequence: $$a_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{r^{n-k}}{k}, \qquad 0 < r < 1.$$

I believe that this sequence converges to $0$ (https://www.desmos.com/calculator/frdzgqwoqd).
I am wondering at what rate, that is, for which $n$ do we have $a_n \leq \epsilon$?
Do you have an idea for how to find this rate?

More generally, can we say that the sequence $$b_n = \sum_{k=1}^n r^{n-k} \cdot c_k, \qquad 0 < r < 1$$
converges to $0$ where $d_n = \sum_{k=1}^n c_k$ is sublinear in $n$?
Is it possible to say something about the rate of convergence depending on the convergence rate of $d_n$?
That is, I am looking for a statement such as: If $\frac{d_n}{n} \leq \delta$ for all $n \geq N(\delta)$ then $b_n \leq f(N(\delta))$ for some function $f$.

Comment: $|a_n|\le r^n\left|\ln\left(1-\frac1r\right)\right|$ (answer by @OlivierOloa borrowed from [a deleted post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1812253/386889)).

Comment: thanks! how would one prove this? I do not have access to the deleted post :)

Comment: Quote from it "**Hint**. One may recall the classic identity
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{u^k}{k}=-\log(1-u),\quad |u|<1,
$$ giving [that]".

Comment: Here is something I proved for the general case. I don’t know if it helps you much but $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{b_n x^n} = \frac{C(x)}{1 - rx}$$ where $$C(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty{c_n x^n}$$ and $|x| \lt 1$. If you had a closed form for $C(x)$ assuming of course that it is convergent, then you could perhaps use something like Cauchy’s integral formula to find the values of $b_n$, however I haven’t tried this so it might not work.

Comment: @AnneBauval I think this might not work here as $r < 1$ (so $u = 1/r > 1$), but please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Oh my bad! this is certainly why the author deleted his answer 7 min after publishing it :( But to the same deleted post there was [a more clever answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1812251/if-mathop-lim-limits-n-to-infty-n-sum-limits-m-1n-fracan/1812253#1812253), by @JackD'Aurizio:$$S_N:=N\sum_{m=1}^{N}\frac{a^{N-m}}{m} = Na^N\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{m=1}^{N}a^{-m}x^{m-1}\,dx=N\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^N-a^N}{x-a}\,dx$$
[...]
$$ S_N \leq N~\frac{1-a^N}{1-a} \int_{0}^{+\infty}\exp\left(-\frac{N-1-aN}{1-a}x\right)\,dx\leq \frac{N}{N-1-aN}.$$

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks! This looks interesting -- though I think this upper bound does not converge to $0$ (and I think $a_n$ should converge to $0$, looking at the function).

Comment: $a_N=\frac{S_N}N.$

Comment: @AnneBauval ah yes! :)

Comment: It can be shown that at $n\to\infty$ and $r\in(0;1)$
$$a_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{r^{n-k}}{k}=\frac1{1-r}+\frac{r}{(1-r)^2}\,\frac1n+\frac{r\,(1+r)}{(1-r)^3}\,\frac1{n^2}+O(1/n^3)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What turned out to be good enough for me is the following, which works when $c_n$ is monotonically decreasing.
In this case, $$(1-r) b_n = (1-r) \sum_{k=1}^n r^{n-k} c_k \leq \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n c_k = \frac{d_n}{n}.$$

Here is why: As $r^{n-k}$ is monotonically increasing in $n$ and $c_n$ is monotonically decreasing in $n$, the inequality is tightest when $c_k \equiv c$ for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$, and hence, it is sufficient to consider this case.
For this case, \begin{align*}
    (1-r) \sum_{k=1}^n r^{n-k} c = c (1-r) \sum_{k'=1}^n r^{k'} = c (1-r) \frac{1}{(1-r)} = c = c = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n c.
  \end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can find the rate of convergence of $b_n$ in terms of $d_n$ using [Abel’s summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula).

Here’s how it would work,

$$b_n \ = \ \sum_{k=1}^n{c_k r^{n-k}} \ = \ r^n \ \sum_{k=1}^n{c_k r^{-k}} \tag{1}$$

$$= r^n \left(d_n \cdot r^{-n} - \int_1^n{d_{[t]} \cdot (-\log r \cdot r^{-t-1}) \ dt} \right) \tag{2}$$

$$= d_n \ + \ \log r \left(\int_1^n{d_{[t]} \cdot r^{n - t - 1} \ dt} \right).  \tag{3}$$

where step $(2)$ came from using the formula.

So if you know what $d_n$ is, then substituting into $(3)$ will give you a formula for $b_n$. You should also expect significant cancellation between the first term and the integral.

Comment: Thanks! Abel's summation formula does look like it is useful here! I am wondering though what to make of this formula as $d_n$ does not necessarily converge to $0$ -- only $\frac{d_n}{n}$ does. I am looking for a statement such as: If $\frac{d_n}{n} \leq \delta$ for all $n \geq N(\delta)$ then $b_n \leq f(N(\delta))$ for some function $f$ (I added this to the question). My intuition tells me that something like this should be possible, but I cannot quite put my finger to it.

Comment: If you know the value of $d_n$ explicitly or if it is close to some ‘nice’ function, then an integration by parts should cancel the main $d_n$ term leaving you with some smaller function. But with an upper bound for $d_n$ like the one you’ve stated, assuming that $d_n$ is positive, I’m struggling to find anything like your bound for $b_n$. If $d_n$ also had some lower bound, in other words $d_n$ is within an interval, then a summation by parts will give you a bound in terms of the length of the interval evaluated at $n$.

Comment: As you can imagine, a closer lower bound for $d_n$ will result in a lower bound for $b_n$.

Comment: I don’t know $d_n$ more precisely. The only thing else that I know is that $c_k$ is monotonically decreasing. This might be useful, as this implies that the first terms (the larger terms) are decayed exponentially by $b_n$ while terms are only decayed uniformly by $\frac{d_n}{n}$, but I myself am not sure yet how useful this can be :) I am not necessarily looking for the tightest possible bound — intuitively I would expect that some bound (which will also depends on $r$) exists